# Syntax for adding/removing CSS class using [ngClass] in Angular based on condition

Tags: css, angular, property-binding

How to add/remove one CSS class when either of the two boolean is true?

```
[ngClass]="{'load': loading , 'load': loadClass}"
```

Comment: `[ngClass]="{'load': loading || loadClass }"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[class.load]="loading || loadClass"
```

OR

```
[ngClass]="{'load': loading || loadClass }"
```

`[ngClass]` can also use a [function](https://alligator.io/angular/class-binding-ngclass-angular/):

```
<div [ngClass]="setMyClasses()">
  ...
</div>
```

Where:

```
setMyClasses() {
  let classes = {
    important: this.isImportant,
    inactive: !this.isActive,
    saved: this.isSaved,
    long: this.name.length > 6
  };
  return classes;
}
```

***This can be extended over various logical evaluation combinations using AND, OR, NOT etc.***

Answer (score 2):

Bind the class name.

Try:

```
[class.load]="loading || loadClass"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[ngClass]="{'load': loading || loadClass }"
```